# How to post and get asmx web serivce access using iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, web-services

I am new to iPhone app development. How can I post data and get data by accessing the asmx web service using iPhone app?

Answer (score 1):

I think asmx webservices are SOAP webservices you should read my blog entry here -

http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/call-soap-web-service-from-iphone/

To call a SOAP service first i create a string with the SOAP request as follows.

```
 NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>n"
        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">n"
        "<soap:Body>n"
        "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">n"
        "<Celsius>50</Celsius>n"
        "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>n"
        "</soap:Body>n"
        "</soap:Envelope>n";


After creating the SOAP request I create a NSMutableRequest to send this request to server.

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

After firing the request we can collect the XML response in the NSURLConnection’s delegate methods.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);
    [theXML release];
}
```

After collecting the XML response in theXML string in -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
we can parse this string using [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) for any other XML parser you like.

Comment: I have added this code and able to run it too but am also getting array as the return param and i need to capture the array list.

Comment: can you please post the response here?

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting an array in webservice response? are you getting that in xml format?

Comment: no i mean I want to process and array list which is returned form the web service i ned to handle it in the iPhone code how do i work on that.

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting array in response (sorry I don't have any .net exp). But if you are talking about getting this data from xml response you can look at this very good library TBXML - http://www.tbxml.co.uk/